# Is there a way to create and fill ListViews from one ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an observable collection based on these data:

[image]

There may be more new data added, so the number of lines in my data can vary (sometimes 2 queries, sometimes 5, ...)

Each line contains a query.

I want to display each query result on a ListView or GridView:

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Label Content="{Binding Type1}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Definition1}"/>
            <ListView x:Name="ListRequete1" AlternationCount="2" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingStyle}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding }" Margin="20" Height="170">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView x:Name="GridViewQuery1">

                   </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
```

Is it possible to do a method:

for each line of the ObservableCollection, I run the query, if the query result is not empty, I create a listView and display the data?

Exemple of final result :

[image]

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Are you saying that you want a ListView (bound to an ObservableCollection) that displays a series of SQL style query commands and then ANOTHER list view that would display the results of one of those queries if selected and executed?

Comment: I just edit with an exemple. My observableCollection contains the "SQLQueries" table which itself contains several queries. Each line of the observable collection contains a request and its description. I want to display the result of each query on the final screen, each with its listview. But there can be up to 20 requests, and I don't know how to do code it properly.

Comment: I've provided an outline answer based on your question, although in a commercial environment I wouldn't advocate it, instead using Datagrids and API/stored procedure calls depending on database accessibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At it's simplest your ListView displays the contents of your `ObservableCollection<SQlQuery>` that is in your ViewModel.
where

```
class SQLQuery
{
  string Query{get; private set;}
  string Description {get; private set;}
}
```

You then implement a command within your ViewModel that is triggered by your ListView ItemSelected or ItemTapped event. This could be handled in your code behind or by binding.
e.g.

```
private void SQLQueryListView_OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var param = (SQLQuery)e.Query;
    if (((ViewModel)BindingContext).RunQueryCommand.CanExecute(param))
    {
        ((ViewModel)BindingContext).RunQueryrCommand.Execute(param);
    }
}
```

The difficulty arises in displaying the resulting data if each query returns data of a different structure or type. For that you may need to consider implementing a specific ContentView for each set of results (each of which contains a ListView) and set their visibility according to which Query is run (if only one to be displayed at any one time)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that's help a lot !